# PHP - Add dropdown options from an array

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array

```
// Output of: print_r($table_data);
Array
(
    [5] => Array
        (
            [0] => hno1
            [1] => hno1
            [2] => hno1
            [3] => hno1
            [4] => hno2
            [5] => hno3
            [6] => hno3
            [7] => hno3
        )

    [7] => Array
        (
            [0] => Mhno1
            [1] => Mhno1
            [2] => Mhno2
        )

    [8] => Array
        (
            [0] => Ehno1
            [1] => Ehno1
        )

)
// Output of: var_export($table_data);
array (
  5 => 
  array (
    0 => 'hno1',
    1 => 'hno1',
    2 => 'hno1',
    3 => 'hno1',
    4 => 'hno2',
    5 => 'hno3',
    6 => 'hno3',
    7 => 'hno3',
  ),
  7 => 
  array (
    0 => 'Mhno1',
    1 => 'Mhno1',
    2 => 'Mhno2',
  ),
  8 => 
  array (
    0 => 'Ehno1',
    1 => 'Ehno1',
  ),
```

```
$row_count = count(max($table_data));
```

Then I'm looping through the result set and output the data

```
for($i = 0; $i < $row_count; $i++){
                        $row = $i + 1;
                        echo "<tr><td>{$row}</td>";
                        foreach($table_data as $column){
                            $items_unique=array_unique($column);
                            $field = $column[$i] ?? NULL;
                            if($field !==NULL){
                                foreach($items_unique as $dropdown_item){
                                    echo "<td><select name=''><option value='strtolower($dropdown_item)'>$dropdown_item</option></select></td>";
                                }
                            }
                            else{
                                echo "<td>$field</td>";
                            }
                        }
                        echo "</tr>\n";
```

Output HTML should look like this:

```
    <table class="table table-responsive table-bordered">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td><select name="">
          <option value="strtolower(hno1)">hno1</option>
          <option value="strtolower(hno2)">hno2</option>
          <option value="strtolower(hno3)">hno3</option>
        </select></td>
      <td><select name="">
          <option value="strtolower(Mhno1)">Mhno1</option>
          <option value="strtolower(Mhno2)">Mhno2</option>
        </select></td>
      <td><select name="">
          <option value="strtolower(Ehno1)">Ehno1</option>
        </select></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>2</td>
      <td><select name="">
          <option value="strtolower(hno1)">hno1</option>
          <option value="strtolower(hno2)">hno2</option>
          <option value="strtolower(hno3)">hno3</option>
        </select></td>
      <td><select name="">
          <option value="strtolower(Mhno1)">Mhno1</option>
          <option value="strtolower(Mhno2)">Mhno2</option>
        </select></td>
      <td><select name="">
          <option value="strtolower(Ehno1)">Ehno1</option>
        </select></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>3</td>
      <td><select name="">
          <option value="strtolower(hno1)">hno1</option>
          <option value="strtolower(hno2)">hno2</option>
          <option value="strtolower(hno3)">hno3</option>
        </select></td>
      <td><select name="">
          <option value="strtolower(Mhno1)">Mhno1</option>
          <option value="strtolower(Mhno2)">Mhno2</option>
        </select></td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>4</td>
      <td><select name="">
          <option value="strtolower(hno1)">hno1</option>
          <option value="strtolower(hno2)">hno2</option>
          <option value="strtolower(hno3)">hno3</option>
        </select></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>5</td>
      <td><select name="">
          <option value="strtolower(hno1)">hno1</option>
          <option value="strtolower(hno2)">hno2</option>
          <option value="strtolower(hno3)">hno3</option>
        </select></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>6</td>
      <td><select name="">
          <option value="strtolower(hno1)">hno1</option>
          <option value="strtolower(hno2)">hno2</option>
          <option value="strtolower(hno3)">hno3</option>
        </select></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>7</td>
      <td><select name="">
          <option value="strtolower(hno1)">hno1</option>
          <option value="strtolower(hno2)">hno2</option>
          <option value="strtolower(hno3)">hno3</option>
        </select></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>8</td>
      <td><select name="">
          <option value="strtolower(hno1)">hno1</option>
          <option value="strtolower(hno2)">hno2</option>
          <option value="strtolower(hno3)">hno3</option>
        </select></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
```

**What I need is for example the first column has three values in common, hno1, hno2 and hno3. I need to display these three values in  all the dropdowns in the first column with the existing value($field) as preselected**.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: A.) How many dropdowns should be displayed for each column?   1,1,1 or 8,3,2 or other?  Please specify.    B.) You need all different values from that column as option so 3 for the first , 2 for the second and 2 for the third column?

Comment: @AlexanderDobernig A) One dropdown for each field in the column if the $field value is not NULL. The values are distinct values of the entire column. B) Yes, 3 for first, 2 for second and 1 for third.

Comment: Use two nested foreach loops.  The inner loop  displays the select inputs. Use array_unique() to show only distinct values.

Comment: foreach($table_data as $column){
$items_unique=array_unique($column);
$field = $column[$i] ?? NULL;
if($field !==NULL){
foreach($items_unique as $dropdown_item){
echo "<td><select name=''><option value='strtolower($dropdown_item)'>$dropdown_item</option></select></td>";
}
}
else{
echo "<td>$field</td>";
}
}

Comment: I tried like above comment but adding only one option.

Comment: So it would be 8,3,2 dropdowns in your example?

Comment: No, only the first value is getting added into the dropdown.

Comment: Please use var_export() for the array and post it inside your question so people can use it to check their scripts.

Comment: Regarding your foreach comment: do the unique too early. You should ONLY do it for the contents of the select not for the foreach  loop itself.

Comment: @AlexanderDobernig I've added the HTML and var_export in the question. Please have a look.

Comment: I saw it and will try it, but one  different important question: if the SELECT NAME is empty nothing will be submitted.. and it does not seem to have a unique id to select with JS ??  This looks wrong?

Comment: @AlexanderDobernig Correct, forget to add name for the dropdown.

Comment: The array you posted now is COMPLETELY different from that before :-(( please export the correct array.

Comment: heat_no  cant be the correct answer -  you have 11+ different selection boxes - you need one unique name for each?!

Comment: The html code diplayed as output cannot be correct.   and you should better add the new content to the question not replace the old content as it may confuse the readers.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/227718/discussion-between-hello-and-alexander-dobernig).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the full working code prototype - annotations explain everything.
**Note:** This will not post any values to a page or do something else as there are no <form> tags inside ... at least it has unique ids for each select so it can be acessed via JS. Please mark the answer as accepted and upvote it if it is the desired result.

Update: 23.01 - 13:29 CET   Inserted the code for the default selection of the element that is initially contained in the array.

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport"
          content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
<?php
$table_data= array
(    3 =>
        array ( ),
        5 =>
        array (
            0 => 'hno1',
            1 => 'hno1',
            2 => 'hno1',
            3 => 'hno1',
            4 => 'hno2',
            5 => 'hno3',
            6 => 'hno3',
            7 => 'hno3',
        ),
    7 =>
        array (
            0 => 'Mhno1',
            1 => 'Mhno1',
            2 => 'Mhno2',
        ),
    8 =>
        array (
            0 => 'Ehno1',
            1 => 'Ehno1',
        ));


//echo "<pre>";
//print_r($table_data); //uncomment these 3 lines to see the array
//echo "</pre><p>";

$number_cols= count($table_data);
//calculate the number of columns

$number_rows = max(array_map('count',  $table_data ) );
//number of rows needed for the table construction
// code taken from a comment from the php manual at count()

$akey=array_keys($table_data);
//as the main array is only associative and we cannot use foreach because of the table structure
// so we create a helper array where we can access the associative arrays in numerical order

// uncomment the next 3 lines to see the array content
//echo "<pre>";
//print_r($akey);
//echo "</pre>";


foreach ($table_data as $col_name =>$array_col) {
    //calculate the content of the selects once per column
    $select_content[$col_name] = array_values(array_unique($array_col));
     //print_r($select_content[$col_name]); //uncomment see what it contains if you are interested
}

echo "<p><table border='1'>";

       for ($i = 0; $i < $number_rows; $i++) {
           echo "<tr> ";
           for ($j = 0; $j < $number_cols; $j++){
               echo "<td>";
              if (isset($table_data[$akey[$j]][$i])) {
               $sname =  $akey[$j] ."-". $i;
               echo "<select name=\"{$sname}\" id=\"{$sname}\">";
               foreach ($select_content[$akey[$j]] as $row => $select_values)
               {   $select_values == $table_data[$akey[$j]][$i]?$selected="selected":$selected="";
                   echo "<option value=\"{$select_values}\" $selected>{$select_values}</option>\n";
               }
               echo "</select> \n";
           }
               echo "</td>\n";}
                  echo "</tr>\n";}
         //   }
    ?>

</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please see this code as example
You have to simply check if inner element is array.

```
  $ar=[
            ['sda','dsads','dasd'],
             ['sda','dsads','dasd'],
              ['sda','dsads','dasd'],
               ['sda','dsads','dasd']
            ];
            
        foreach ($ar as $item){
            if(is_array($item)){
                $select='<select>';
                echo $select;
                foreach ($item as $list){
                    echo "<option>".$list.'</option>';
                }
                echo '</select>';
            }
        }
```

[here is the working link of code](https://paiza.io/projects/P1ediDopC0wFKXlCC9kCLg)

Comment: This was my first thought, but in this case this did not work because the \<tr><td> structure of the table  was not reproducaeable by foreach's without any bizarre transformations that noone could understand easily.